# Игнорирование части названий файлов в Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, webview

У меня есть простой список из `listView` и массива. При нажатии на элемент списка открываются файлы `n0.txt`, `n1.txt`.

В чём собственно проблема: нужно, чтобы андроид  студио как бы игнорировал часть названий,что бы можно было писать так `n0weapon.txt`, `n1fuel.txt` и т.д? Вот код который какраз таки "выводит txt файлы"

```
public class activity_stigmata_detail extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("title", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext();    

        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
                "raw", "com.coldgames.honkaiimpact"));

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    }    

    private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)  {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Объясни понятнее, что надо, и желательно с примерами. Тут люди простые, твою тарабарщину могут не понять.

Comment: Я вот за всё время существования Андроида так и не понял: Зачем пытать `id` ресурса по имени в рантайме, если и то, и другое известно ещё на момент компиляции, а имя ресурса и вовсе задаётся самолично при написании кода?

Comment: плюсую. понятно, что что-то проектое, но не понятно что нужно. Что лично нме понятно из вашего описания: есть файлы n0.txt , потом часть его названия должна быть проигнарирована и получиться n0weapon.txt. Не кажется ли вам это полным бредом? Вот и мне кажется. Исправьте, и тогда мы вам с легкостью поможем.

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно велосипед на костылях, но сделать всё же можно, используя рефлексию:

```
    private static int getRawResId(String prefix) {
        for (Field field : R.raw.class.getFields()) {
            if (field.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
                try {
                    return field.getInt(null);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {}
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Естественно при условии, что ресурсы берутся из **своего** же приложения